# FLUTTER can not connect to tcp SOCKET in another flutter program SocketException: Connection refused

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sockets, tcp

I'm new to Dart and Flutter. I know a bit about Sockets. Here is my question:

I tried to create a TCP socket on a emulator with flutter (on android emulator Pixel 3A API 33) and connect it with another emulator(identical but diffrent emulator, Pixel 3A API 33). I got en error it says "Connection Refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111),address = 0.0.0.0, port = 36802)

I'm trying to make p2p chat application using flutter. I'm creating a socket in here in p1:

```
myPort = 43761;
    String mysocketIP = "0.0.0.0";
    final Future<ServerSocket> mySocket = ServerSocket.bind(mysocketIP, myPort);
```

and listening the socket like this in p1:

```
mySocket.then((ServerSocket listenSocket) {
        listenSocket.listen((Socket mysocket) {
          mysocket.listen((Uint8List data) async {
            String mysocketResponse = String.fromCharCodes(data);
            String strData = utf8.decode(data);
            if(mysocketResponse == "///initiate"){
              p2pSocket.add(utf8.encode("Got you message"));
            }
            print(strData);
          });
        });
      });
```

All code in p1 about socket is given.
And here comes p2, which is client. Trying to connect to p1:
(I'm getting relevant port and ip from a server. That part works fine, I tested. serverResponse is the response from server. recKey means reciever's key. Its not relevant to my problem. Just another stuff.
code comes to else if block and executes but in Socket.connect line it blows.

```
late String recieverClientIP;
     late int recieverClientPORT;
    /*
    ...
     ...
    */
    else if(serverResponse.length>=8 && serverResponse.substring(0,8)=="//recKey") {
        targetsKey = serverResponse.substring(8);
        // p2p sohbeti baslatıyoruz.
        p2pSocket = await Socket.connect(recieverClientIP, recieverClientPORT);
        //p2pSocket.write("///initiate");
      }
    ;
```

Here is the erros message I get:
[ERROR MESSAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AgqB.png)

I realized that in error, it says another port number. I'm using (IP 0.0.0.0) port number 47761 in p1 and in error it says another port number. Maybe it about it? I don't know I'm so confused.

By the way I'm using Android Stuido. With Emulator. Emulator I'm using is Pixel 3A API 33 x86 64

EDİT: I'm using 10.2.2.2 in Server, 0.0.0.0 in p1. I can not create a socket with 10.0.2.2 in p1 it gives error. That's why I'm using 0.0.0.0 it's working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not try to connect a client app on an emulator with a server running on another emulator. Too difficult. You have to be a network expert to do so. Dont know if it is even possible.

Comment: 10.0.2.2 is for a client running on an emulator to connect with a server running on the same pc as the emulator is running on.

Comment: p1? What is p1? And dont bind a server socket to an ip. Just open the port. Only if you are forced to bind then bind to 0.0.0.0 as then all incoming connections can be accepted.

Comment: p1 is just a name. peer1. I was actually trying to make a p2p chat app. I have a server and 2 peers. Peers connects to the server and then finds each other, I mean get the ip and port number of each others serverSocket. I get it, that's terrible. Then how can I achieve this? All I want is to peers communicate each other without server. @blackapps

Comment: What if I run the one peer on a real device, my phone and run the other peer on emulator. In the end, program will run on a real device. Is the problem in here I'm using emulator? @blackapps

Comment: `recieverClientPORT` needs to be the same as the server port 43761

Comment: Yes that is still problematic. Just use two devices. Maybe server on device and client on emulator will be doable.

Comment: @Hydra why? I'm I'm done with server. Server's only mission is to provide information to peers for connection. For example: We have Peer A (IP 0.0.0.0 PORT 43761) , PEER B(IP 0.0.0.0 PORT 47500) and Server (IP 127.0.0.1 PORT 55555). A and B connects to Server and gives information about ip and port. And also learns each other's ip and port. Now Server's mission is done. A wants to connect B from B's socket(IP and PORT).  You're saying that B's port is useless and I should use Server Port. Why?

Comment: I'm confused, are running a server o both peer A and B? Else why are you trying to connect to server that does not exists, If you have only ONE server then every peer should connect to that server's port

Comment: Server exists. In the beginning, Peer A and B connects to the server. Because they don't know each others socket(IP and PORT). They connect to server and learn each others information. Server only mission is this. Then Peer A creates a socket. Peer B tries to connect to peer A by that socket. Thats my plan. But I can't. 
I hope I was able to explain the issue. Do you have any suggestions? @Hydra

Comment: I see what you're trying to do but the peer A should be a serversocket not a socket and the port should be A's port then peer B should connect to A using this information, you can't  connect a socket to another socket

Comment: Can I start chat with you? If you have time? Help would be really appreciated. It won't take much time. @Hydra

Comment: It's not just a socket. Peer A has a serverSocket. "final Future<ServerSocket> mySocket = ServerSocket.bind(mysocketIP, myPort);" like this. @Hydra